# Can WS02 IS offer ADFS compatible IDP?

Tags: wso2, adfs, wso2-identity-server

Can WS02 IS offer ADFS compatible IDP for federation of 3rd party apps requiring ADFS - without actually using active directory or active directory tools?

Comment: Will this article be helpful to you https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/ ?

Comment: Not quite. I do not have any Windows or AD infrastructure and trying to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS02 is an IDP. ADFS is an IDP. By ADFS compatible, you mean that it supports the same protocols ADFS supports i.e.

- WS-Fed
- SAML
- OpenID Connect

It can so in that sense it's ADFS compatible.

Is there a specific ADFS function that you require?

Comment: Is ADFS just WS-Fed, or a particular implementation of WS-Fed that is not compatible with others? I have a few apps that claim to need ADFS rather than SAML or OIDC, but know next to nothing about the MS Win techs.

Comment: @Tom We have implemented wso2is to be IdP for multiple systems coupled originally with ADFS with SAML and WS-Fed. I cannot say there were no pains, but wso2is is capable to fulfill IdP role for saml and ws-fed (passive profile). What could be hard are aps directly reading from AD (LDAP) with hardcoded attribute names

Comment: No - ADFS implements all three - all the WS-Fed implementations should be compatible. Client side may be a problem ? e.g. OpenID Connect is implemented client-side via ADAL which is a Microsoft library.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.